# How to prove that this function all over the positive integers gives us this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

On the first hand, I have this sequence : $0,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,...$ which is the sequence where an $n$ positive integer appears $n+1$ times consecutively.

On the other hand, I have this function : $a_n=\lfloor\frac{\sqrt {1+8n}-1}{2}\rfloor$ where $n\ge0$

$a_0=0$ ; $a_1=1$ ; $a_2=1$; $a_3=2$

This function seems to be a formula for this sequence.

However, if it is the case, how can we prove it ?
And if it isn't, what is the explanation ?

To begin with, i did something :

$\frac{\sqrt {1+8n}-1}{2}=t+b$ where $t\in \mathbb N$ and $b\in [0,1[$

After some simplification, i get this :

$8n= 4t^2+4b^2+8tb+12t+12b+8$

After this, i don't know how to continue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Idea:**

In the sequence, $a_n$ becomes $m$ when $n=\sum\limits_{i=0}^m i=\dfrac{m(m+1)}2$; i.e., $m^2+m-2n=0$.

Solving this quadratic for $m$, we get $m=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{1+8n}}2$.

Answer (score 2):

The first entry of $k$ in your sequence comes in position $T_k=\frac 12k(k+1)$
If you use the quadratic equation, this gives $k=\frac {-1+\sqrt{1+8k}}2$

Comment: Thanks i didn't notice the sum !